# converting a generic list to string array

Tags: vb.net, list, .net-3.5

I have a generic List(Of Customer). The customer class has a name, address, and phone number properties. I also have a property of another class that accepts a customer name array. I am able to do this by doing the following:

```
Dim names As String()
Dim i As Integer = 0
'customer.GetCustomers is a List(of Customer)
For Each customer As Customer In customer.GetCustomers()
     ReDim Preserve names(i)
     names(i) = customer.Name
     i += 1
Next
```

Then to set it:

```
'CustomerNames is a String()
Class.CustomerNames = names
```

Is there a better way to convert this to a string array? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use LINQ (Pardon my VB, I prefer C#)

```
Dim queryResults = From cust In customer.GetCustomers() Select cust.Name
Class.CustomerNames = queryResults.ToArray()
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I was able to change it to: Class.CustomerNames = (From cust In customer.GetCustomers() Select cust.Name).ToArray

Thanks for your help.